# Optimize the process of multiple argument passing to class constructor

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I'm writing a desktop app using C#.Net and SQL server. i have several calss constructor with several parameters that each time i should pass them to. below is an example :

```
 Classes.Prices prices = new Classes.Prices  
 (comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(),
  Convert.ToInt32(txtPrice.Text), 
  Convert.ToInt32(txtCarbohydrate.Text),   
  Convert.ToInt32(txtProtein.Text),   
  Convert.ToInt32(txtFat.Text), 
  Convert.ToInt32(txtHumidity.Text), 
  Convert.ToInt32(txtminerals.Text));
```

is it any way to overcome this and prevent much coding for converting and passing multiple arguments 
to constructor ?

Comment: One option is to define an overload of the constructor which takes strings instead of ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use more that 2 to 3 parameters in a method.

Define a class called `PriceHolder`

```
public class PriceHolder
{
    public string FirstValue { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Carbohydrate { get; set; }
    public string Protein { get; set; }
    public string Fat { get; set; }
    public string Humidity { get; set; }
    public string Minerals { get; set; }
}
```

And then, your constructor must accept an object of `PriceHolder`

like this:

```
public Prices(PriceHolder hold)
{
 // access the values by hold.Fat, hold.Minerals etc
}
```

This method makes refactoring the code easier, or if you intend to add some more properties.

Also, your fellow programmers will be able to easily understand it. Readability matters!

Comment: Jokiyou mean a separate class ? cause i've already defined a calss like this? then how can i get the values of text boxes to that clas, again much coding ?

Comment: you can access the values using `hold.Fat`

Comment: what problem happens if i use more than 3 parameters in a method ?

Comment: There is no problem, but it is unorganized and it can be a mess, if you wanted to add some more parameters. As I said, readability matters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. Use data binding to bind your forms to objects. Data binding converts in both directions automatically, i.e. from strings to numbers and dates and back.

Besides the advantage of having an automatic conversion, you have the advantage that you can separate the business logic from your form. You can apply any logic to a property called `Prices.Price` (or just `Price` if the logic is inside the `Prices` class), for instance, instead of applying it to a construct like `Convert.ToInt32(txtPrice.Text)`, which makes it a lot easier to understand and maintain the code.

In order to use data binding add a public default constructor (a constructor with no parameters) to the class and a public property for each value.

```
public class Prices
{
    public Prices () 
    { }

    public Prices (decimal price, int carbohydrate, ...) 
    { ... }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Carbohydrate { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

See:

[Data Binding for Windows Forms](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84476/data-binding-for-windows-forms/) (on developerfusion)

[Data binding concepts in .NET windows forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3665/Data-binding-concepts-in-NET-windows-forms) (on CodeProject)

---

A completely different way of approaching your problem is to normalize you data. Introduce a `Parameter` class and store the parameters in dictionary or in a list in the `Prices` class. This enables you to process the parameters in loops instead of having to program each parameter individually. It also has the advantage of being expandable with a minimum of coding.

```
public class Parameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Prices
{
    public Prices (IEnumerable<Parameter> parameters) 
    { 
        ... 
    }
}
```

Comment: this is exactly i was looking for a long time, i want to be able to write standard , high performance and professonal apps nice advise on separation of business logic, how can i write standard and optimized code , can you suggest me some sources to read ?

Comment: There is a design pattern called Model-View-Controller (MVC). Google this term and the terms "data binding", "object data binding", "winforms" and so on. [c# separate business logic from forms data binding](https://www.google.ch/search?q=c%23+separate+business+logic+from+forms+data+binding)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help. Let the `Price` construstor to be as follows:

```
public Prices(string s, int[] values)
{
    ...
}
```

Let's declare this static method in the form:

```
private static int[] ParseInts(params TextBox[] textBoxes)
{
    return Array.ConvertAll(textBoxes, tb => int.Parse(tb.Text));
}
```

Then the constructor call became:

```
Prices prices = new Prices(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(), 
    ParseInts(txtPrice, txtCarbohydrate, txtProtein, txtFat, txtHumidity, txtminerals));
```

**EDIT.** You can also store a set of texboxes as array instead of create it each time on the fly:

```
private readonly TextBox[] textBoxes = new[] { txtPrice, txtCarbohydrate, txtProtein, txtFat, txtHumidity, txtminerals };

Prices prices = new Prices(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(), ParseInts(textBoxes));
```

Comment: nice approach , why did u use a static method ?

Comment: Just for instance. It can be easily replaced with a parameterless non-static method, that uses the `textBoxes` array.